# adwords api and MCC account and how to add customer ID in report

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using the python adwords api v201402.

I have an mcc account.

```
        report_downloader = self.client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201402')
        # Create report definition.
        report = {
            'reportName': 'Last 7 days CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
            'dateRangeType': 'LAST_7_DAYS',
            'reportType': 'CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
            'downloadFormat': 'CSV',
            'selector': {
                'fields': ['CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'CriteriaType',
                           'Criteria', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost']
            },
            # Enable to get rows with zero impressions.
            'includeZeroImpressions': 'false'
        }

If I dont add a customer ID I get the below error:
    output, return_money_in_micros)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleads-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/googleads/adwords.py", line 406, in _DownloadReport
    raise self._ExtractError(e)
googleads.errors.AdWordsReportBadRequestError: Type: AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_INVALID
Trigger: <null>
Field Path: None
```

How do I add a customer id?  I tried adding 'clientCustomerId':"xxx-xxx-xxx" in the hash but I get the below:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds_jurko-0.6-py2.7.egg/suds/mx/core.py", line 71, in append
    if self.start(content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds_jurko-0.6-py2.7.egg/suds/mx/literal.py", line 86, in start
    raise TypeNotFound(content.tag)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'clientCustomerId'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but hopefully this might help others stumbling onto this question.

If you have multiple clients for whom you need to explicitly set the clientCustomerId outside of your yaml, in the instance where you have one MCC but multiple clients, you can do the following:

```
self.client = AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
self.client.SetClientCustomerId(<client_customer_id>)
```

After that, you can use the report downloader as needed, and you can re-assign the customer ID as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `clientCustomerId` is set within your API client object.

Depending on your goals, you should either set this value in a config file, or in your `client` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your [Googleads.yaml](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads.yaml) file is configured correctly and in your home directory. I got a similar error and that fixed it.